# ASMX web service and The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error issue

Tags: c#, web-services

i have developed a very small web service and which is hosted along with our web site. our webservice url is http://www.bba-reman.com/Search/SearchDataIndex.asmx

### web service code

```
namespace WebSearchIndex
{
    #region SearchDataIndex
    /// <summary>
    /// SearchDataIndex is web service which will call function exist in another library for part data indexing
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    public class SearchDataIndex : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        //public AuthHeader ServiceAuth=null;
        public class AuthHeader : SoapHeader
        {
            public string Username;
            public string Password;
        }

        #region StartIndex
        /// <summary>
        /// this function will invoke CreateIndex function of SiteSearch module to reindex the data
        /// </summary>
        [WebMethod]
        public string StartIndex(AuthHeader auth)
        {
            string strRetVal = "";
            if (auth.Username == "Admin" && auth.Password == "Admin")
            {
                strRetVal = SiteSearch.CreateIndex(false);
            }
            else
            {
                SoapException se = new SoapException("Failed : Invalid credentials", 
                SoapException.ClientFaultCode,Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,new Exception("Invalid credentials"));
                throw se;
            }
            return strRetVal;
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

}
```

when i was calling that web service from my win apps using `HttpWebRequest` class then getting error **The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error**

### here is code of my win apps from where i am calling web service

```
    string strXml = "";
    strXml = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><s:Body><StartIndex xmlns='http://tempuri.org/' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'><auth><Username>joy</Username><Password>joy</Password></auth></StartIndex></s:Body></s:Envelope>";
    string url = "http://www.bba-reman.com/Search/SearchDataIndex.asmx";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "text/xml";
    req.KeepAlive = false;
    req.ContentLength = strXml.Length;
    StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    streamOut.Write(strXml);
    streamOut.Close();
    StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
    streamIn.Close();
```

i am just not being able to understand when this line execute `StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());` then getting the error **The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error**

not being able to understand where i made the mistake. mistake is in the code of web service end or in calling code?

help me to fix this issue. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what i recommend is the following:
-you get rid of the httpwebrequest.

- add a service reference to your application which will generate the proxy class.

-finally add this code  :

```
ServiceReference1.SearchDataIndexSoapClient Client = new ServiceReference1.SearchDataIndexSoapClient();
        ServiceReference1.AuthHeader authHead = new ServiceReference1.AuthHeader();
        authHead.Password = "Admin";
        authHead.Username = "Admin";

        Client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout= new TimeSpan(0, 5, 00);
        Console.WriteLine(client.StartIndex(authHead));
```

That should be it

Comment: what is ExtensionData; ? i am getting error when i add this line in code

Comment: when this line execute client.StartIndex(authHead) then i am getting error like "The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)." i guess content type is getting issue

Comment: how could i set content type at client side when calling service by adding reference ? or do i need to set any content type in the web service code?

Comment: Just Get rid of extension data

For the error , it seems you don't have the rights to execute the service so instead of receiving a soap xml response you're getting an HTML error page if I am guessing right you should see an HTMl page included with the response

Comment: can anyone tell me what i need to do at web service code level as a result content type response would be text/xml not text/html.

Comment: adding this line DataIndex.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout= new TimeSpan(0, 5, 00); solve timeout issue